# all group members but the current row

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a grouped data frame, like so:

```
df <- data.frame(group = rep(1:4, each=3),
                 lets = rep(LETTERS[1:4], times=3))
```

For each row I would now like to identify all `lets` within the same group other than the `lets` of the row itself. Using `dplyr` I can get *all* `lets` thus:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(all_lets_in_group = paste(lets, collapse=','))
```

But how do I exclude the `lets` of the current row from what I feed into `paste()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of this task is not very clear, so the code clarity thus suffers as well, but still:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    all_lets_in_group = lets %>% 
      map(function(l) setdiff(., l)) %>%
      map_chr(function(x) paste(x, collapse=',')))
```

Uses set operation `setdiff` to subtract current letter provided by `purrr::map` from the group's set, then reformats the list of vectors with `paste` and returns as character vector.

Comment: You can clean up the code and get a better golf score with using formulas.       `map(~setdiff(lets, .x))`  and `map_chr(~paste(.x, collapse=','))`

Comment: @JakeKaupp I may be doing this wrong, but as a drop-in replacement into the above the formulas don't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about a `dplyr` solution, but you can use `lapply`.

```
df$all_lets_in_group <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) 
    paste(with(df, lets[group == group[x] & lets != lets[x]]), collapse = ','))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R method that uses `ave`, `sapply`, and `setdiff`

```
ave(df$lets, df$group,
    FUN=function(i) sapply(i, function(j) paste(setdiff(i, j), collapse=",")))
 [1] "B,C" "A,C" "A,B" "A,B" "D,B" "D,A" "D,A" "C,A" "C,D" "C,D" "B,D" "B,C"
```